# Using RasterToNumpyArray and numpy instead of Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, numpy, array

I have 5 rasters (6 bands, but only need bands 0, 1, and 5) for which I need to calculate several vegetative indices, including the Excess Red Index (ExR) and Color Index of Vegetation Extraction (CIVE). Since ExR and CIVE have non-integer constants, spatial analyst keeps promoting the output to 64-bit double-precision which makes binary thresholding impossible. I have demonstrated that this is the problem because I also calculated the Excess Green Index (ExG) and get a 32-bit floating point output. With numpy, I can explicitly control the bit-depth of the final output but I don't know how to carry out the calculation.

The formulas for the indices are:

- ExG = 2g-r-b -->note that this is an integer constant
- ExR = 1.4r-b
- CIVE = 0.441r - 0.881g +0.385b + 18.78745

where r, g, and b are normalized (e.g. r = red/red+green+blue, g = green/red+green+blue, ...)

Here is my attempted script:

```
# Assume that I already have a list called 'composites' containing 5 rasters, and lists of all the relevant geotransform data
nparrays = []
for i, raster in enumerate(composites):
   nparrays.append(arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster, nodata_to_value=raster.noDataValue).astype(float))
# apply formula
CIVE_arrays = []
for date, numpyarrays in enumerate(nparrays):
    CIVE = np.zeros_like (numpyarrays, np.float32) #empty arrays to fill with CIVE calculation
    r = numpyarrays[0,:,:] # ndarray is in format [bands:cols:rows]
    g = numpyarrays[1,:,:]
    b = numpyarrays[5,:,:]
    CIVE = 0.441*(r/r+g+b) - 0.881*(g/r+g+b) + 0.385*(b/r+g+b) + 18.78745 # this is not correct (script runs but output is all black when converted back to raster)
```

Can anyone recommend how to use numpy to run this calculation? Using non-Esri Python packages (GDAL, RasterIO, etc.) is not an option due to restrictions on the computer I am using.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud as I've not done much with numpy arrays. May be you need to declare them to be of type float/double so the calculation functions as expected?

Comment: You mention the CIVE output is all black, suggesting it is populated with uniform values? What is the value? Also, what version of Python are you working in?